# Nginx refuses connection on some blocks but not others

Tags: nginx

I have a problem where I've defined several server blocks to redirect traffic. My nginx config looks like:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name deflector.io www.deflector.io;

    return 301 https://www.deflector.io$request_uri;

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name deflector.io;

    return 301 https://www.deflector.io$request_uri;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/deflector.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/deflector.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    root /home/foundation/deflector/app/build;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/deflector/deflector.access.log;

    server_name www.deflector.io;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.htm $uri.html /index.html;  
    }

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/deflector.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/deflector.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Traffic to `http` works fine and gets redirected as expected, however traffic to `https://deflector.io` is rejected with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to deflector.io port 443: Connection refused`. This is despite the last block serving just fine.

I'm kind of out of ideas here, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure you're connecting to the same server?

Comment: Check your DNS records and ensure that `deflector.io` and `www.deflector.io` both point to the same IP address.